# How to override taxonomy page with users view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

When I enable provided views, it works all right. But for one taxonomy dictionary (let's name it *dictionaryname*), I want to display users in that taxonomy, not nodes. So I disabled default view again and then:

- I created "show users" view with path `taxonomy/term/%` and it fails to replace taxonomy page.
- Then I changed path to `dictionaryname/%` - as path alias is set. But it fails as well.
- I changed path to `aaa/%` and it works, so I know view on it's own works. It just fails to override default pages.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? And how can I get `dictionaryname/%` path to work?
It looks like Drupal's router give original term pages precedence over my view.

Comment: I dont know if you are using tvi module or not, but latest version of module causes this problem, even if it's not used and is only enable

Comment: @Sohail I do not. Maybe I should? And maybe it's not exactly module's bug if I can get the very bug without module at all?

Comment: well I guess you can do exactly what you want with this  module, try the latest dev version anyway and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Sohail tvi fails miserably, taxonomy practically does not work anymore. Not a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per reviewing [`taxonomy_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_menu/7) function, you need to replace path `taxonomy/term/%` with `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` in "show users" view.

If you want to use path alias, set view path like this: `dictionaryname/%taxonomy_term`

Also, check Taxonomy and Views modules weights, make sure Views module weight is higher than Taxonomy module.

Comment: I don't quite get what are you trying to tell. Path in view does not work for me no matter is it `taxonomy/term/%` (as in provided, working view), `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` or `dictionaryname/%taxonomy_term`. It looks like Drupal's router give original term pages precedence over my view.

Comment: I tried it before I post my answer. I was able to see the new created page view instead of the original taxonomy term view.

Comment: Lucky you. Now, what should I test to find out why my router does not work that way? :(

Comment: Thanks. Check Views module weight in `system` table, make sure its higher than Taxonomy module.

Comment: OK, this was the case. Now I really get the view I need. It's empty, but that's templating problem I guess. But it sets the correct title.

Comment: Sounds like a good news so far.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your question, here is a scenario that should help ::
(This implementation was done for D6. It will also work for D7 with some changes)

// Say, module name is 'common_operations'

1. Invoke hook_menu_alter

```
    //Overwriting term page display 
    if (isset($items['taxonomy/term/%'])) {
      $items['taxonomy/term/%']['title'] = '';// Give title you need
      $items['taxonomy/term/%']['page callback'] = 'common_operations_taxonomy_page_display_callback';
      $items['taxonomy/term/%']['page arguments'] = array(2);
      $items['taxonomy/term/%']['access arguments'] = array('access content');
    }
```

1. Defines 'common_operations_taxonomy_page_display_callback'

   ```
   function common_operations_taxonomy_page_display_callback($tid){
     $term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
     switch($term->vid) {
       case 1: //Blog Tags vocab.
         $blog_tags  = '';
         ............................
       return $blog_tags;
       case 2: //Issues vocab.
         $issues  = '';
         ............................
       return $issues;
       case 3: //Tags vocab.
         $tags  = '';
         ............................
       return $tags;
       default:
         // Returns the default term page provided by taxonomy module.
         module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.pages');
       return taxonomy_term_page($tid);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Here, Blog Tags, Issues, Tags are different vocabularies. So, whatever changes we need for different vocabulary term details pages, we can take care off independently.

Hope it helps.